# Trouble Inputting two short int's C++

Tags: c++

> Declare two short integer type variables (var7 and var8) and take their values using only one >>, that is, do this input in the same statement. Display the result

I believe I have the code all set up, just not sure if it's how I am inputting the info (5 "spacebar" 5) or how the code is laid out. However, the value for int 8 is always some crazy number, like 28900.

```
printf("enter an integer for var7 and var8 \n");
short int var7, var8;
cin >> var7, var8;
printf("Short integer value 7 is %d \n", var7);
printf("Short integer value 8 is %d \n", var8);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `std::cout`?

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  Either use the C-Style I/O, ex: printf, scanf; or use C++ I/O, ex: cout, cin.  Don't do things like using `cin` and `printf`.  They may have conflicts in the implementations.

Comment: [Adjust your compiler warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bT58xx1fM) At the very least, you know exactly where something is fishy and have a solid warning to search.

Comment: I am only allowed to use printf for this part of the assignment.  Otherwise I would not for sure!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Agree, [Don’t cross the streams.](https://quotegeek.com/quotes-from-movies/ghostbusters/206/).

Comment: unit5016 Use `<<, >>` or `fgets,scanf,printf` or seek a more knowledgeable assignment maker.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Not `scanf`...

Comment: @unit5016:  It makes no sense to use one "<<" two read two separate variables.  Nevertheless... Have you studied about C/C++ [unions](https://www.codespeedy.com/union-in-cpp-with-examples/) yet?  It would allow you to declare a *single* variable that could contain two "short" ints.

Answer (score 2):

For your own benefit, research the comma operator:  "C++ comma operator".

In the mean time, this is how you input two variables:

```
std::cin >> variable_1 >> variable_2;
```

You may want to space separate them when entering on the console.

**Edit 1: The program.**
FYI, here's your program using C++ streams:

```
std::cout << "enter an integer for var7 and var8 \n";
short int var7;
short int var8;
std::cin >> var7 >> var8;   // Look ma, no comma!                              
std::cout << "Short integer value 7 is " << var7 << "\n";
std::cout << "Short integer value 8 is " << var8 << "\n";
```

Comment: I'm required to use printf for just this section, as well as cin. However, the question asks for input using only one >> so I do not think your answer follows the rules? Unless I'm missing what the instructor wants.

Comment: @unit5016 "*Unless I'm missing what the instructor wants*" - clearly, you are, because you can't read 2 values with 1 `>>`

Comment: @unit5016: if you have two variables (e.g. var7 and var8), and you want to read both in a single statement... then `std::cin >> var7 >> var8;` is absolutely the correct, "standard" way to do it.  Q: Is this some kind of "programming challenge" that's asking you to think of some "non-standard" (e.g. "clever") alternative?  Where did this "requirement" come from?  Are you sure you understood it correctly?

Comment: @paulsm4 Hey that is why I am asking on this website haha. Every other section of the assignment has not been some mad scientist non-standard question which is why this phrasing in the assignment stood out. The question literally states "using one >>" so maybe my brain is incompatible with how everyone else is seeing this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some people love fun, so have fun:

**Option 1**

```
int main()
{
    printf("enter an integer for var7 and var8 \n");
    short int var7, var8;

    short int* ptrs[] = { &var7, &var8 };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ptrs)/ sizeof(ptrs[0]); ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> (*ptrs[i]);
    }

    printf("Short integer value 7 is %d \n", var7);
    printf("Short integer value 8 is %d \n", var8);
}
```

**Option 2**

```
#define fun(x) { std::cin >> x; }

int main()
{
    printf("enter an integer for var7 and var8 \n");

   short int var7, var8;
   fun(var7)
   fun(var8)

   printf("Short integer value 7 is %d \n", var7);
   printf("Short integer value 8 is %d \n", var8);
}
```

Of course, this is just fun-purpose code, but it fits the requirements.

Comment: You're still mixing the streams.  Please don't mix the streams.  Provide two versions, one using only C style I/O and another with C++ I/O.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I can't make head nor tail of your comment. What do you mean? Why "only C style"? Why mixing two streams? It is said in the requirement "do this input in the **same statement**". You can't do in the same statement both in C and C++.

Comment: What I am saying is that don't use `cin` and `printf` nor `scanf` and `cout`.  You should provide two examples.  One that uses only C-style I/O and another that uses only C++ I/O.

Comment: Once again, how this comes from the initial requirements in the question? This seems to be your assumptions, not the requirements. Can you please quote how your statement is supported by the initial question? Nothing is said in the question about "don't use cin", etc. If you want striker conditions, feel free to raise your own question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take multiple inputs in `cin` then use variable separated by `>>` operator

change

```
 cin >> var7, var8;
```

to

```
cin >> var7>> var8;
```